# SQL CASE WHEN ELSE not working in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, group-by, case, amazon-athena

I have the script below setup in AWS Athena, the goal is to replace *some* budget numbers (total) with 0 if they are within a certain category (costitemid). I'm getting the following error in AWS Athena and could use some advice as to why it isn't working. Is the problem that I need to repeat everything in the FROM and GROUP BY in the WHEN and ELSE? Code below the error. Thank you!

*SYNTAX_ERROR: line 6:9: 'projectbudgets.projectid' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
This query ran against the "acorn-prod-reports" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: 077f007b-61a0-4f6b-aa1f-dd38bb401218*

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid IN (462561,462562,462563,462564,462565,462566,478030) THEN (
        SELECT
        projectbudgets.projectid
        , projectbudgetyears.year fiscalYear
        , projectbudgetyears.status
        , "sum"(((0 * projectbudgetlineitems.unitcost) * (projectbudgetlineitems.costshare * 1E-2))) total
    )
    ELSE (
        SELECT
        projectbudgets.projectid
        , projectbudgetyears.year fiscalYear
        , projectbudgetyears.status
        , "sum"(((projectbudgetlineitems.quantity * projectbudgetlineitems.unitcost) * (projectbudgetlineitems.costshare * 1E-2))) total
    )
END
FROM
  (("acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgets projectbudgets
INNER JOIN "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetyears projectbudgetyears ON (projectbudgets.id = projectbudgetyears.projectbudgetid))
INNER JOIN "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetlineitems projectbudgetlineitems ON (projectbudgetyears.id = projectbudgetlineitems.projectbudgetyearid))
--WHERE (((projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid <> 478030) AND (projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid < 462561)) OR (projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid > 462566))
GROUP BY projectbudgets.projectid, projectbudgetyears.year, projectbudgetyears.status
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in AWS Athena, but from my point of view this sql is not correctly built up because you use a case-when for the purpose of conditionally changing your Select-parts of your sql. But normally the result of a case-when is _one_ column in your resulting table. As far as I understand your code, you have projectbudgets that consist of many projectbudget-lineitems and you want to sum up the costs for each project but for specific line-items (i.e. 462561,462562,462563,...) you want to have a value of 0 contributing to the sum. Is that correct?

Comment: By the way, your where-clause is not active, correct? It looks a little bit strange because you have the condition that the line-item-nr is smaller than 462561 AND is not equal to 478030, that means the second part of that condition is included in the first part so it is obsolete. And the other part of the where-clause is line-item-nr is bigger than 462566 so be aware of the fact that the line-item-nr=478030 will _not_ be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong (at least according to most SQL dialects.)  You can't generally say `"SELECT CASE WHEN (condition) THEN (this select clause) ELSE (that select clause) END FROM (tables)"`

You can only use `CASE` to calculate a *single value*.

But it looks as if the only change between your two inner `SELECT` clauses is whether you use 0 or the quantity in the final multiplication. And *that* is perfect for a `CASE`!

I do not guarantee this will work right off the bat, because I don't have your setup or an idea of your table layout. However, it's a step in the right direction:

```
SELECT
  projectbudgets.projectid
, projectbudgetyears.year fiscalYear
, projectbudgetyears.status
, "sum"(
    ((
       CASE
         WHEN projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid IN (462561,462562,462563,462564,462565,462566,478030) 
         THEN 0
         ELSE projectbudgetlineitems.quantity
         END * projectbudgetlineitems.unitcost
     ) * (
       projectbudgetlineitems.costshare * 1E-2
     ))) total
   
FROM
  (("acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgets projectbudgets
    INNER JOIN 
    "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetyears projectbudgetyears 
       ON (projectbudgets.id = projectbudgetyears.projectbudgetid))
    INNER JOIN "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetlineitems projectbudgetlineitems 
       ON (projectbudgetyears.id = projectbudgetlineitems.projectbudgetyearid))
  GROUP BY 
    projectbudgets.projectid, projectbudgetyears.year, projectbudgetyears.status
```

Comment: This seems to have worked as I was hoping for! I need to do some data checks to make sure but thank you so much Ann!

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem if you want to sum the items for each project and year and status except for certain line items. Here, it is correct to use a "where" condition and not "case when" :

```
SELECT
projectbudgets.projectid, 
projectbudgetyears.year, 
projectbudgetyears.status,
"sum"(((projectbudgetlineitems.quantity * projectbudgetlineitems.unitcost) * 
(projectbudgetlineitems.costshare * 1E-2))) total
FROM
  (("acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgets projectbudgets
INNER JOIN "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetyears 
 projectbudgetyears ON (projectbudgets.id = projectbudgetyears.projectbudgetid))
INNER JOIN "acorn-prod-etl".target_acorn_prod_acorn_projectbudgetlineitems 
 projectbudgetlineitems ON (projectbudgetyears.id = 
  projectbudgetlineitems.projectbudgetyearid))
WHERE projectbudgetlineitems.costitemid NOT IN 
 (462561,462562,462563,462564,462565,462566,478030) 
GROUP BY projectbudgets.projectid, projectbudgetyears.year, 
 projectbudgetyears.status
```

;